# Parameters Alignment in swift functions like Objective -C

Tags: objective-c, swift, readability

I had written a function in Objective-C like this,

```
-(void)addView:(UIView *)view belowView:(UIView *)viewAbove aboveView:(UIView *)viewBelow withHeight:(CGFloat)height{
// Code goes here
}
```

When putting line breaks in between the parameters, they were neatly auto aligned like this,

```
-(void)addView:(UIView *)view
     belowView:(UIView *)viewAbove
     aboveView:(UIView *)viewBelow
    withHeight:(CGFloat)height{
// Code goes here
}
```

The same did not happened for swift, and these long functions looked not so readable

```
private func addView(view: UIView,
                     belowView viewAbove: UIView,
                               aboveView viewBelow: UIView,
                                         withHeight height: CGFloat) {
}
```

How can I align long function's like I used to do in Objective-C

**Xcode Version on which I have tried is 7.3.1**

Comment: I have to say, theese are some quite confusing external vs. internal parameter names.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Yeah! :). I have to change that too.

Comment: This is a bug. It has been fixed in the latest beta version of Xcode.

Comment: @jtbandes After you commentI tried it on Xcode 8.0 beta too. Did not worked. Which version are you on?

Comment: @BangOperator 7.3 it perfectly worked and compiled the code without errors !

Comment: @AaoIi, I think you are getting confused in readability of function as accessibility of that function. Please read the tag "Readablity" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/readability

Comment: @BangOperator Ok let me see it , probably I have misunderstanding !

Comment: I confirm what jtbandes said, it's an Xcode bug and has been resolved in Xcode 8 beta: it aligns correctly now ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOy-qak1jZxAOowyi0I41-7o5V0zh4aE_nQ)).